# How does inheritance work in this bit of code?

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

So guys I've been playing around with inheritance and I've stumbled upon this program :

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    static class A {
        void f() { System.out.println("A"); }
    }

    static class B extends A {
        void f() { System.out.println("B"); }
    }

    static class C {
        void func(B b) { b.f(); }
    }

    static class D extends C {
        void func(A a){ a.f(); }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ( (new D())).func( (A) (new B()));
        A a =  new B();
        a.f();
        B b = new B();
        C c = new D();
        c.func(b);
    }
}
```

So how come even though A and C are implemented exactly the same way in the final few lines, A's methods
get overriden by B, but C's don't get overriden by D?
The program prints as follows : 
B
B
B

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the line marked with //1 print 57 instead of 39?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60269396/why-does-the-line-marked-with-1-print-57-instead-of-39)

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Probably the worst dupe target ever. Such an awful title and badly formatted question.

Comment: Not that this question has any better title.

Comment: @ruohola it's just that I remembered that question and it's basically the same. If you find a better one I'll gladly retract mine.

Comment: I tried writing a simpler title but it said it was already taken sorry guys! I edited it into something I think is a bit better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Class D function definition is more general than C. C's function takes B type parameter but D function takes type A parameter which is a parent of B. It is more general than a function defined in C.

```
static class D extends C {
    void func(A a){ 
        a.f(); 
    }
}

  B b = new B();
  C c = new D();
  c.func(b);
```

Variable c is pointing to D's object so c.func(b) invokes method defined in D. A is a parent of B hence B's method is called. Same as it is called using A's reference as shown below.

```
  A a =  new B();
  a.f();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the method `func` in `D` does not override the same of `C` as the signature change.

```
static class C {
    void func(B b) { b.f(); }
}
static class D extends C {
    void func(B a){ a.f(); }
}
```

This will result in an override of the method

Comment: Well that certainly explains why C's isn't overriden, but how come when I upcast B to A it still uses B's function?

Comment: Because of polymorphism and the method having the same signature

Comment: Yeah apparently I had it the other way around, so was D overwriting C's method? and can the (upcasted) A object use any of B's methods if there were any other ones exclusive to B?

Comment: D will have two methods at runtime, one for signature A and for for B, so depending on the runtime type it will use the correct method. For the second question, i'm quite sure the answer is "no", but you can try it yourself ;)